# Need help in finding the location of the replicated file on my hdfs cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I am using Webhdfs for storing a file in my hdfs cluster. In the conf files I have mentioned the replication factor as 2. Using the Webhdfs api, the first PUT request tells us location of the datanode to put the file on and using the address in the response we put the actual file in the datanode using the 2nd PUT request. Now since we have mentioned that the replication factor is 2, the file will get replicated to another datanode and we know the location of the 1 of the 2 files, is it possible to get the location of the 2nd file, as to which datanode it is located on? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, files in HDFS are not stored as a whole. Rather they are chopped into blocks and these blocks are stored in a replicated manner across the cluster. So your question should be how to find the location of the second replica of a block and not the file.

You can point your web browser to `namenode_machine:50070`, the HDFS webUI. Click on `Browse the filesystem` and move to the file in question. Once you click on this file a new page will be opened. Scroll down to :

```
Total number of blocks: 1
-4906713039323389639:       127.0.0.1:50010
```

This shows you all the block of this file and the machine where they are placed.

HTH

Comment: So, i had a question, for putting a file in hdfs, the first request is a put request which returns which datanode to direct the next put request to. So does the namenode behave like a load balancer and return that datanode who has the least node, or it returns the same datanode location always.

Comment: The request is redirected to a nearby datanade which has free blocks to accommodate the data. It's not the same datanode everytime.